# Android Git client with revert support

Tags: android, software-development, version-control, git

I’m looking for a for Git client on Android that can do `git revert <sha>` (in addition to pull and push).

There are many well-featured Git clients in Play store, but I haven’t found one with revert support yet.

Comment: As there's no answer yet, and to not leaving you "standing in the rain": [Versioning with Git](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_versioning#group_963) has a list of all Git clients for Android currently available on Google Play. That should it make easier for you to check whether there's one with this specific feature.

Answer (score 1):

[**MGit**](https://github.com/maks/MGit) (a successor of SGit) will have revert support as soon as the [related issue](https://github.com/maks/MGit/issues/27) is solved.